# Передать переменную из одной функции в другую

Tags: python, telebot

Есть вот такой код, мне нужно как-то передать переменную words из цикла в функцию step_proceed (последняя строчка). У меня есть идея насчет глобальных переменных, но можно ли как-то обойтись без них?

```
def callback_handler(call):
    db = Database('db/database.db')
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    for category in db.get_categories():
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=category['title'], callback_data='category_' + category['callback_name']))
    if call.data == 'start_quiz':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Привет, устрою вам небольшой экскурс. Когда вы выбираете категорию, появляются новые слова, под каждым словом есть 2 кнопки. Когда вы нажимаете "Не знаю" - вам ничего не начисляется. При нажатии "Подсказка" ,у вас снимется 0.5 бала(если вы напишете правильный ответ). Если вы напишете перевод верно, вам зачислится 1 очко. Игра до 10 очков. Удачи!')
        time.sleep(11)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выберите категорию {}'.format(emoji.emojize(':down_arrow:')), reply_markup=markup)

    for category in db.get_categories():        #выполнение колбеков через цикл, используя БД
        if call.data == 'category_' + category['callback_name']:
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Не знаю", callback_data='dont_know')
            btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Подсказка", callback_data='hint')
            markup.add(btn1, btn2)
            words = db.get_words(category['title'])
            random_word = words[random.randint(0, len(words))]
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Ну что ж, да начнется битва! Даю вам время 30 сек, иначе...", parse_mode='Markdown')
            time.sleep(2)
            msg = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, ("Впишите перевод: " + str(random_word['translation']).capitalize()), parse_mode='Markdown', reply_markup=markup)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, step_proceed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и без `lambda`:

`bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, step_proceed, words)`

Comment: А 3 параметр это будет как аргумент для 2?

Comment: сообщение, функция "следующего шага", аргументы функции (может быть не один)

Answer (score 2):

Глобальные переменные не нужны. Лямбда собирает вместе функцию и данные:

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, lambda: step_proceed(words))
```