# Мне необходимо, чтобы пользователь сам мог обозначить переменную, написав сообщение в Телеграм-чат с ботом

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь мог сам ввести переменную city. Как можно это реализовать?

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'],commands=['weather_now'])
def weather_now(message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id='1321525541',text='Введите город, который вас 
интересует')
    time.sleep(5)
    city = 'Москва'
    mrg = owm.weather_manager()
    observation = mrg.weather_at_place(city)
    w = observation.weather

    temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
    hym = w.humidity
    detailed_status = w.detailed_status
    wind = w.wind()['speed']
    clouds = w.clouds

    bot.reply_to(message, 'В городе {} сейчас температура {} по Цельсию, 
{}.'.format(city, temp, detailed_status, wind))
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Влажность: {}%\nОблака: {}%\nСкорость ветра: {} м/ 
с\n'.format(hym, clouds, wind))
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Хорошего дня!')
```

Comment: через FSM - т.н машину состояний, если вам нужно вводить название города после сообщения о вводе города.

Comment: уже было и не раз https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1209804/234134