# Может ли Бот в телеграм (pyTelebotAPI) задать вопросы и затем переслать ответы на все вопросы одним сообщением?

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Уважаемые пользователи, привет!
Подскажите, пожалуйста:
Необходима функция от телеграмм бота - чтобы бот задал вопросы пользователю, который обратился к нему и затем итог перенаправил в группу.

условный алгоритм:
/start - как дела? - дела хорошо! - как жизнь? - отлично! /end.

bot.forward_message - дела хорошо!, отлично!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1386065/234134