# проблема с register_next_step_handler

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Люди знающие, столкнулся с проблемой, при втором использовании register_next_step_handler бот перестает передавать значения, да и в целом сама функция эта перестает работать везде...

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text", "sticker", "pinned_message", "photo", "audio"])
def handler(message):
    data = sqlite3.connect('databasee.db', check_same_thread=False)
    db = data.cursor()
    Inline_texts1 = db.execute("""SELECT * FROM inline_texts""").fetchone()
    data.commit()
    town_kb = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
    town_kb.row(f"{Inline_texts1[0]}", f"{Inline_texts1[1]}")
    town_kb.row(f"{Inline_texts1[2]}", f"{Inline_texts1[3]}")
    town_kb.row("◀️Вернутся в главное меню")
    if message.text == "Изменить текст кнопок":
        if message.from_user.id == config.adm:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Выбери, где нужно изменить текст у кнопок:", reply_markup=edit_inline_text_kb)
    if message.text == "Изменить города":
        if message.from_user.id == config.adm:
            edit_town = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"На данный момент в боте следующие значения:\nГород 1 - {Inline_texts1[0]}\nГород 2 - {Inline_texts1[1]}\nГород 3 - {Inline_texts1[2]}\nГород 4 - {Inline_texts1[3]}\n\nВыбери город для изменения:", reply_markup=town_kb)
            data.commit()
            bot.register_next_step_handler(edit_town, edit_town_text)
 
def edit_town_text(message):
    global new_town
    new_town = message.text
    new_text_town = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Теперь напиши новое название к городу:", reply_markup=return_kb)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(new_text_town, edit_new_text_town)
def edit_new_text_town(message):
    if new_town == f"{Inline_texts1[0]}":
        db.execute("""UPDATE inline_texts SET city1 = ?""", (message.text,))
        data.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"✅Вы успешно изменили текст кнопки на {message.text}")
    elif new_town == f"{Inline_texts1[1]}":
        db.execute("""UPDATE inline_texts SET city2 = ?""", (message.text,))
        data.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"✅Вы успешно изменили текст кнопки на {message.text}")
    elif new_town == f"{Inline_texts1[2]}":
        db.execute("""UPDATE inline_texts SET city3 = ?""", (message.text,))
        data.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"✅Вы успешно изменили текст кнопки на {message.text}")
    elif new_town == f"{Inline_texts1[3]}":
        db.execute("""UPDATE inline_texts SET city4 = ?""", (message.text,))
        data.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"✅Вы успешно изменили текст кнопки на {message.text}")
```

Comment: Попробуйте без глобальной переменной https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1386065/234134

Comment: Благодарю! Но я уже решил проблему таким образом, еще раз спасибо!